# How can I rank a list in Processing from the lowest to the largest number

Tags: list, processing, rank

[Processing screenshot of a piece of the list I would like to rank from the lowest number to the largest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT3Iv.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Create a class that encapsulates a data item. Something like this:

```
class RankedString{
   String thing;
   int rank;

   public RankedString(String thing, int rank){
      this.thing = thing;
      this.rank = rank;
   }
}
```

**Step 2:** Create an `ArrayList` of instances of that class:

```
ArrayList<RankedString> list = new ArrayList<RankedString>();

void setup(){
   list.add(new RankedString("thing one", 27));
   list.add(new RankedString("thing two", 64));
   //add the rest of your items
}
```

**Step 3:** Use `Collections.sort()` and a custom `Comparator` to sort the `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<RankedString> list = new ArrayList<RankedString>();

void setup(){
   list.add(new RankedString("thing one", 27));
   list.add(new RankedString("thing two", 64));
   //add the rest of your items

   Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<RankedString>(){
      public int compare(RankedString rs1, RankedString rs2){
         return Integer.valueOf(rs1.rank).compareTo(rs2);
      }
   });
}
```

In the future, you should really try to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and go through [the question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) before posting.